# Facebook share button not shown up on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, facebook

On my client website As i see in debug mode Facebook share button is there but not displaying on screen here is my client website:

https://headtalker.com/campaigns/just add drumcorps-2/

Click on invite friend link.

Please help me out its seriously confused stuff.every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The share button is not showing up for me in any browser.

I think it's caused by a Javascript error on your page:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined line 22
optimizeiframes.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Most likely you need to include jquery. Try putting this near the top of your html file (preferably in the head):

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I'm not sure what optimizeiframes is trying to do, but this may fix it. When Javascript errors out on the page, there can be all kinds of problems. In Chrome try pressing F12 to view errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks sricks i am checking now

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Abhi if not showing button of facebook in firefox, review with 'web developers' of firefox if this button contain a width and height, it's possible that is button have width and height with a 0.

In this case you can add new css and apply new size.

example:

```
.fb_iframe_widget span {
display: contents !important;
}

.fb-share-button.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
  width:100px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
}
```